# Exposing multiple task manager metrics running on the same host

Tags: apache-flink

I'm running Flink on Yarn and i wanted to gather some metrics to see how things are. I've found some guides on how to configure Flink > Promehteues > Grafana combo, but i've noticed, that currently without any customizations, just:

```
 metrics.reporters: prom
 metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
 metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9999
```

On prometheues when i query for this cluster (i have 4 hosts), I get metrics for single Task Manager for each host. In total there are about 30 TM's and i thought that I'll get metrics for all of them.
With:

```
flink_taskamanger_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_max{instance="<host>"}
```

I'm getting only 1 result ( There are 8TM's running there i promise :) )

I've tried fiddling with scopes but without success. Is there a simple way to expose metrics from multiple TM's running on single host?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone by any chance finds this, the resolution is to assign a port range equal or more to the amount of Task Managers that are running on single physical machine e.g:

```
 metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9989-9999
```

Each TM is separate entity that requires separate port to publish metrics.